# slicing a list as if it has the behavior of a ring buffer

Tags: function, filter, coq

To create a slicing function that has the lower and upper index and the size of the list as parameters so that when slicing the list given those parameters, it behaves like a gather function.

I've tried to define it using the filter concept and provide it with the testing function. Please see my code below

```
Require Import PeanoNat.
Require Import Coq.Init.Datatypes.
Require Import Notations.
Import Basics.

Fixpoint filter_index {X: Type} (currInd : nat) (test: nat -> bool) (l: list X ): list X :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | h::t =>  if test currInd then h :: filter_index (S currInd) test t else filter_index (S currInd) test t
  end.

Definition slicing_ring (tail head sz: nat) : nat -> bool :=
  fun n => if sz <=? head then orb ( n <=? head mod sz) ( tail <=? n) else andb ( tail <=? n) (n <=? head).

Example test1 : filter_index 0 (slicing_ring 3 5 4) [6;9;3;4] = [4;6;9].
```

So in the above example, I expect to have the result list. However, if I do `Compute filter_index 0 (slicing_ring 2 3 4) [6;9;3;4].` it gave me `[6;9;4]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `filter_index` function is never going to change the order of the elements of the list. The elements are tested in order and then conditionally inserted into the output in order.

A better approach might be based on indexed access.

```
Fixpoint get_index {X: Type} (ls: list X) (index: nat): option X :=
  match ls, index with
  | [], _ => None
  | x :: _, 0 => Some x
  | x :: tl, S index' => get_index tl index'
  end.
```

(this is essentially `nth_error` from [the standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html) — there are variants for other kinds of access).

If you can enumerate the indices for your ring buffer slice in the desired order, this should work fine.